# Does any C++ Component Framework beyond Corba Components exist?

Tags: c++, frameworks, components, corba

I'm looking for a C++ Component Framework like EJB3 (sure, it's Java only) or Corba Components. But I'm not looking for Corba Components.

My requirements are

- portable (linux, unix, optional Windows)
- C++ interfaces (so, it's not a requirement for the framework itself to be written in C++)
- optinal well documented or good examples given

*edit:*

- *remote objects (remote procedure call) shall be supported. [XPCOM does not support remote objects]*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um, that's an area I have no expertise in, but I always thought ACE would be what you're looking for. Grüße, sbi

Comment: ok, TAO is the ACE ORB. I always understood ACE as network communication framework that provides some pattern

Comment: ACE is a rich network and MT dedicated framework/library. TAO is an ORB built on top of it. ACE can be used standalone. By using ACE, we are not obligated to define a CORBA component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm aware of a few things. I'm only remembering of (I don't have access to my bookmarks file)

- [ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/index.html)
- [Facebook's Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/)

*I know there are other component oriented frameworks in C++*.

Comment: Do you know these "other component oriented frameworks"? What I left out as I assumed it's included is the word distributed.
ICE looks good, I'll test it.

Comment: I cannot remember their name right know. I'll have a look at my bookmarks next week to see what I can dig out.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla's [XPCOM](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/xpcom/) is a mature, portable component framework.

Comment: I edited my question; XPCOM does not support remote objects, but I want this feature

Answer (score 1):

I have used ZeroC's ICE in the past and generally been impressed by it.  It meets all of the requirements that you have put forth.

Comment: This answer was already given, but thank you for writing your experience.

Answer (score 1):

[PocoCapsule](http://code.google.com/p/pococapsule) is an open source and portable C++ component assembly and deployment framework that supports CORBA and WebServices etc. remote components. It is well documented with rich examples.

Comment: ok, thanks for your contribution. but this is a very small two men show... It's very dangerous to rely on such projects.

Comment: I know that it's over three years, but the "it's very dangerous" because it's a two man show comment is just ludicrous (in a *no one gets fired from buying IBM* kind of way.)