# template behavior based on existence of a function

Tags: c++, templates, hashcode

I have a template class foo

```
template <typename Item>
class foo
{
    void method()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

what I need is to change the implementation of the method, based on the type Item, based if  a function say `unsigned int hasher(const Item& item)` exists.

My question is - how is this technically possible and if not how I could organize the code to have this?

Note the performance is a big deal for the algorithm and I am looking for solutions that will allow the compilers to solve the difference compile time.

Comment: based if a function exits? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8814869/1810087

Comment: The [pretty printer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) uses traits that determine whether a type has member functions extensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply template policies, take a look at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design
also
[C++ templates](http://books.google.gr/books?id=yQU-NlmQb_UC&pg=PA284&lpg=PA284&dq=c%2b%2b%20templates%20traits%20policies&source=bl&ots=EepM65VwG-&sig=0VJoJpgrSRQVJG-3vF4rIDS1Hfc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-RnCUsGtN-ukyAObr4CYCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=c%2b%2b%20templates%20traits%20policies&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't touched c++ code for years now so can't write you an example on the spot [well maybe I could but the results would be hilarious] but as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature) the powers you seek can be found in [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Macro helper to create traits
#define HAS_TEMPLATED_FUNC(traitsName, funcName, Prototype)                          \
    namespace detail {                                                               \
    template<typename U>                                                             \
    class traitsName                                                                 \
    {                                                                                \
        typedef std::uint8_t yes;                                                    \
        typedef std::uint16_t no;                                                    \
        template <typename T, T> struct type_check;                                  \
        template <typename T = U> static yes &chk(type_check<Prototype, &funcName>*); \
        template <typename > static no &chk(...);                                    \
    public:                                                                          \
        static bool const value = sizeof(chk<U>(0)) == sizeof(yes);                  \
    };                                                                               \
    }                                                                                \
    template <typename U>                                                            \
    struct traitsName : std::conditional<detail::traitsName<U>::value,               \
                                         std::true_type, std::false_type>::type {}
```

Now assume that:

```
unsigned int hasher(const int& item);
```

Now create the trait:

```
HAS_TEMPLATED_FUNC(has_hasher, hasher, unsigned int (*)(const T&));

// some test.
static_assert(has_hasher<int>::value, "");
static_assert(!has_hasher<char>::value, "");
```

Now, there is some way to use it

Tag dispatching:

```
template <typename Item>
class foo
{
public:
    void method()
    {
        method(has_hasher<Item>());
    }
private:
    void method(std::true_type)
    {
        // You may use hasher here.
        hasher(Item{});
    }
    void method(std::false_type)
    {
        // You cannot use hasher here.
    }
};
```

or SFINAE:

```
template <typename Item>
class foo
{
public:
    template <typename T = Item>
    typename std::enable_if<has_hasher<T>::value, void>::type
    method()
    {
        // You may use hasher here.
        hasher(Item{});
    }

    template <typename T = Item>
    typename std::enable_if<!has_hasher<T>::value, void>::type
    method()
    {
        // You cannot use hasher here.
    }
};
```