# How to check during runtime whether a class method exists

Tags: c++, methods, ld-preload

I am writing a library which gets preloaded using LD_PRELOAD to different versions of other code (which I don't want/cannot change). In a former version, a class method A::foo() of class A exists and in a later version, it doesn't.

For global (C-like) function, I am using the **attribute**((weak)) mechanism to check whether a function is actually defined when running the code:

```
void foo() __attribute__(weak));
if (foo) { foo(); }
```

That doesn't seem to work for class members.

The compile-time error is:

```
no ‘int somenamespace::SomeClass::someFunction()’ member function declared in class ‘somenamespace::SomeClass’
int somenamespace::SomeClass::someFunction() __attribute__((weak));
                                                                                     ^
...
./file.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void somenamespace::OtherClass::initialize()’:
./file.cpp:397:32: error: ‘class somenamespace::SomeClass’ has no member named ‘someFunction’
         num = theinstance.someFunction();
```

**Is there a way to check for existance which does not rely on the definition being known at compile time?**

I cannot use templates as in [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) because I templates are evaluated during compilation.

Also, [How to Check if the function exists in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814705/how-to-check-if-the-function-exists-in-c-c) was of no help.

Comment: All info about a function's existence is already known at compile-time; thus a compile-time solution is the best way to go. Keep in mind that C++ is not a dynamic language.

Comment: I agree, how is it that you do not know if it exists? Unless you are loading a DLL at runtime and querying for functionality?

Comment: @tenfour: As I wrote in the first sentence, I am writing a library which gets preloaded using LD_PRELOAD. That means, that at the time I am compiling the library, I do not know, to which other (version of) code it gets preloaded.